# Model binding two or more collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Has anyone had any luck model binding two or more collections using the code posted by Phil Haack here: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)?

As an example, I have the below code.

```
public class Book {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Author {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult Index(List<Book> books, List<Author> authors) {
  // Will never model bind two collections.
}
```

The HTML that I have is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="books.index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="books[1].Name" />

<input type="hidden" name="books.index" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="books[2].Name" />

<input type="hidden" name="authors.index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="authors[1].Name" />

<input type="hidden" name="authors.index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="authors[1].Name" />
```

The exception that I get is:

> The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'authors' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Book], System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Author])' in 'HomeController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Book]', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Author]'. Parameter name: parameters

Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported by ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You don't need the hidden fields to store the index value - as you are using Lists. Also, the indexs should start at 0.

Comment: According to the blog, I need to use a hidden field to store the index value if I am going to delete or dynamically add new items. Since my view allows items to be deleted, I need the hidden fields.

Comment: I would also like to add that if I remove one parameter from the action method, the other binds without any problem. For instance, if I removed the authors parameter from the action method, the books parameter would correctly bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere else, I was unable to reproduce. The following works fine for me:

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<Book> books, List<Author> authors)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <input type="text" name="books[0].Name" value="book 1" />
    <input type="text" name="books[1].Name" value="book 2" />

    <input type="text" name="authors[0].Name" value="author 1" />
    <input type="text" name="authors[1].Name" value="author 2" />

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

It successfully binds values back in the POST action.

---

UPDATE:

I confirm that this is a [bug in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2](http://forums.asp.net/p/1632006/4207598.aspx) which will be fixed in the RTM. As a workaround you could put the following in your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: You are correct. On an empty solution, it works fine. I am suspecting the problem to be in Sharp Architecture's model binder. I am trying to isolate the problem at the moment.

Comment: It seems that the problem could be in ASP.NET MVC3 RC2 as I tried the code posted above in a new solution and I am getting the same errors.

Comment: @Husain, you are right. This very much looks like a bug in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2. I am able to reproduce it. I would be very interested as to why this happens and couldn't find any information in the Breaking Changes section of the accompanying Release Notes document.

Comment: Neither was I able to find any information. Now I need to figure out how I can submit a bug report.

Comment: @Husain, see my Update. It is indeed a bug and it will be fixed.