# Entity Framework 4.1 CodeFirst Problem MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, entity, code-first

I have a very strange problem using the latest the EF 4.1 with CodeFirst which I think is comes from a one to one relationship I have.

The problem is weird in that I have two differet controllers with unrelated entities that allow me to list and save an ICollection of an entity.

```
http://localhost:51638/DailyHours/Edit/1 and

http://localhost:51638/HoursRemaining/Edit/1
```

Both work in isolation.  For example I enter one first, edit and save (works).  I then enter the second,edit and save and it doesn't work.  The error I get is:

> The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'dailyHours' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[App.Domain.DailyHours])' in 'App.Web.Controllers.DailyHoursController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Domain.HoursRemaining]', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[App.Domain.DailyHours]'. Parameter name: parameters

If I reverse the order in which I edit and save I get the same error but with the DailyHours and HourRemaining in reverse.

The key aspects of the pocos are:

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual HoursRemaining HoursRemaining { get; set; }
}

public class HoursRemaining
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

DailyHours has no direct relationship to either of these:

```
public class DailyHours
{                      
    [Key]
    public int DailyHoursId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sprint Sprint { get; set; }
}
```

I have added code in my context's OnModelCreating to establish the principle in the one to one relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasOptional(h => h.HoursRemaining).WithRequired(t => t.Task);
```

I can't fix this problem at all.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered here. [Model binding two or more collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417426/model-binding-two-or-more-collections)

thanks